# Script throws MySqlException with syntax error message

Tags: c#, mysql, logfiles

I want to save the system log in MySQL database and this is my code

```
EventRecord record;
while ((record = reader.ReadEvent()) != null)
{
    using (record)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}: {2} : {3}   {4}", record.TimeCreated, record.LevelDisplayName, record.FormatDescription(), record.Id, record.LogName);
        var time = record.TimeCreated;
        String Displayname = record.LevelDisplayName;
        String Description = record.FormatDescription();
        String log_name = record.LogName;
        int id = record.Id;

          string server;
          string database;
          string uid;
          string password;

        MySqlConnection conn;
        server = "localhost";
        database = "logfile";
        uid = "root";
        password = " ";

        string connetionString;
        connetionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";SSL Mode=none;";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connetionString);
        string insertQuery = "insert into syslog (Time,Record_d,log_name,Display_Name,Description)values (@ time,@id,@log_name,@Displayname,@Description)";
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", record.TimeCreated);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", record.Id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@log_name", record.LogName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Displayname", record.LevelDisplayName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", record.FormatDescription());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

My script end with the following error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 's success status was true. The last
>   boot's success status was true.')' at line 1'

Comment: Have you tried removing the space between @ and time in (@ time,@id,@log_name,@Displayname,@Description)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql) _`Time` is a reserved word._

Comment: use something other than @ time use @ timeCreated and do not forget to delete the space

Comment: Prachi and jiri Hernik i had solved the error by removing the space between @ time. thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove space of @ time and add space before "values", that should do the trick

Comment: Thanking you, did u know how watch log file using wmi and how to save the current log